# Change color of Zxing frame on scan

Tags: iphone, objective-c, zxing

I am working on a QR code scanner using ZXing and was wondering if there was a way to change the color outline of the frame after a successful scan, much like the Scan App in the appstore does.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's possible, but it takes customization/effort. The color is hard coded in `OverlayView.m`. You'd need to make it not hardcoded and then tell the overlay view to redraw itself at the appropriate times.

Alternatively/FWIW, what I do is "flash" the screen: I add a full screen white view and then fade it away, a bit like the flash on a camera. That doesn't require any interaction with the lower level code and, personally, I like the effect better, at least in my context.